# $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}} a_{n-1}$, for $n \geq 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, pointwise-convergence

Let $a_{1}=2020, \\
a_{2}=2021,\\ a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{n^{2}} a_{n-1}$, for $n \geq 2$.

Then which of the following is correct?

A) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2020}$.

B) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ is divergent.

C) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2021}$.

D) None of the above.

In this question option A and C are incorrect. Since the first term of the sequence is $\frac{1}{2020}$.

What about the option $B$?

Answer (score 3):

The series is divergent. Let $C=2021$. Notice that $a_n\leq C n$ for $n\in \{1, 2\}$. We want to prove this for every integer $n$. The base case of the induction is done and, the induction step follows easily as
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{1}{n^2}a_{n-1}\leq Cn+ \frac{C(n-1)}{n^2}\leq Cn+C\frac{1}{4}<C(n+1).$$

So
$$ \sum_n \frac{1}{a_n} \geq \frac{1}{C}\, \sum_{n} \frac{1}{n}=\infty,$$
since the harmonic series is divergent.

Comment: $\frac{1}{a_n} \ge \frac{1}{C n}$ so the last line should be $$\sum_n \frac{1}{a_n} \ge \frac{1}{C} \sum_n \frac{1}{n} = \infty$$

Comment: Yep, I was just thinking about a constant* harmonic series lower bound. But, of course, if such C is the previous one then it appears in the denominator.

Comment: Also, no need to begin the series from $2020$, the inequality was proved for all positive $n$. That just baffles the reader.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know why I wrote it from $n=2021$. It is edited.